# Prepare Array for CSV

Tags: php, arrays, csv

first of all:
I've solved this problem by myself. But I want to know, if there is better way to do it.

I've got the task to reorder a csv for a better overview.
we have an export from a tool to show all users and there printers in a windows client network.

i want to transform it to a list where each column contains the users of one  printer.
something like this:

```
printer1 printer2 printer3
user1    user2    user1
         user3    user2
```

My source looks like this: http://pastebin.com/DdeHuB79

I've solved this by collecting all printers and then collecting all users for each printer.
it is a very slow solution, cause i'm reading the hole csv per printer...

My current solution: http://pastebin.com/dAiZS2Ck

one of my first attempts: http://pastebin.com/1JDpBH67

Do any one have a better idea of rearranging these items?

**EDIT 1:**
my array should look like this, to put it to the csv correctly:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [printer1 => user1
            [printer2 => user2
            [printer3 => user1 
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [printer1 => 
            [printer2 => user3
            [printer3 => user2
        )
)
```

Comment: You could use `file()` and `explode()` and read it just once.

Comment: thank. but i don't care of opening the file more than one time. yes, it is faster to check an array than a file. but i want to reduce the count of loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can read printers and users at the same time.

```
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ';','"')) !== FALSE)
            {
                    $printer = trim(strtolower($data[1]));
                    $user = trim(strtolower($data[0]));

                    $printers[$printer][] = $user;                        
            }
```

Comment: i did something like this before. but i need all values for a printer in each line (one array element). see my update

Comment: You can increase the input size 4064